# Google Compute Engine quota module not in kernel

Tags: drivers, kernel, disk-usage, quota

I was trying implement disk user and group quotas at Google Compute Engine with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but till now i'm unsuccessful.

Quota allows you to specify limits on two aspects of disk storage:
the number of inodes a user or a group of users may possess; and the number of disk blocks that may be allocated to a user or a group of users.

The idea behind quota is that users are forced to stay under their disk consumption limit, taking away their ability to consume unlimited disk space on a system.

```
sudo -s
apt-get -y install quota quotatool
nano /etc/fstab
```

then I used

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0 0 0
```

then I tried activate quota:

```
mount -o remount /
quotacheck -avugm
quotaon -avug
quotaon: using //quota.user on /dev/sda1 [/]: No such process
quotaon: Quota format not supported in kernel
```

Quota module not in kernel, I create the user and group quota.

```
touch /aquota.user /aquota.group
chmod 600 /aquota.*
mount -o remount /
quotacheck -avugm
quotaon -avug
quotaon: using //quota.user on /dev/sda1 [/]: No such process
quotaon: Quota format not supported in kernel
```

Didn't work.

I remembered a way used in AWS EC2:

```
apt-get -y install linux-image-extra-virtual

echo quota_v1 >> /etc/modules
echo quota_v2 >> /etc/modules

reboot

sudo -s
cat /proc/modules | grep -i quota
```

Nothing, Didn't work either.

```
modprobe quota_v1
modprobe: FATAL: Module quota_v1 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic

quotaon -pa
group quota on / (/dev/sda1) is off
user quota on / (/dev/sda1) is off
```

I made this work at EC2 but no luck with Google Compute Engine.
Any idea what I can try more?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution. I do not need install linux-generic at EC2 but seems need be a procedure at Google Compute Engine.
All procedure to get quota work:

```
sudo -s
apt-get -y install quota quotatool

nano /etc/fstab
```

Edit fstab:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0 0 0
```

Check for missing packages.

```
dpkg -s linux-generic
dpkg-query: package 'linux-generic' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

We need install the missing linux-generic package:

```
apt-get -y install linux-generic
```

Also the extras packages:

```
apt-get -y install linux-image-generic
apt-get -y install linux-headers-generic
apt-get -y install linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
```

We need add the quota modules to start with boot:

```
echo quota_v1 >> /etc/modules
echo quota_v2 >> /etc/modules

reboot
```

Check if it's working:

```
sudo -s
cat /proc/modules | grep -i quota

quota_v1 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc037c000
quota_v2 16384 2 - Live 0xffffffffc0377000
quota_tree 20480 1 quota_v2, Live 0xffffffffc0250000

quotaon -pa

group quota on / (/dev/sda1) is on
user quota on / (/dev/sda1) is on
```

Both quotas are activated.